# Remove table if contains string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am looking to automatically remove tables in slides if they contain a specific text string. This is what I currently have, but for some reason, the findText() doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out an alternative to this...

```
function removeUnwantedTables() {
var gotSlides = 
SlidesApp.openById('1gJjGBbaQXWhP8uhVIoccV2h_RL7_gsxvg_NW-qNCcLU').getSlides();

  for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
    var slide = gotSlides[i];
    var tables = slide.getTables();

    for (var k = 0; k < tables.length; k++) {
      var allTables = tables[k];
      if (allTables.findText('{{remove-this-table}}') > 0) {
      allTables.remove();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: The reason that findText doesn't work is [there is no findText method of class Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there may be several answers. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Using [`getCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table#getCell(Integer,Integer)), each cell are retrieved and compared to the string of `{{remove-this-table}}`.

  - I couldn't find the method for directly searching the string from a table. So I used this.
- When `{{remove-this-table}}` is found, the table is removed and the for loop is broken away.

#### Modified script :

```
function removeUnwantedTables() {
  var gotSlides = SlidesApp.openById('1gJjGBbaQXWhP8uhVIoccV2h_RL7_gsxvg_NW-qNCcLU').getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
    var slide = gotSlides[i];
    var tables = slide.getTables();
    if (tables.length > 0) {
      for (var k = 0; k < tables.length; k++) {
        var allTables = tables[k];
        row = allTables.getNumRows();
        col = allTables.getNumColumns();
        var values = [];
        for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {
          for (var c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            var v = allTables.getCell(r, c).getText().asString();
            if (v.indexOf("{{remove-this-table}}") > -1) {
              values.push(v);
              break;
            }
          }
          if (values.length > 0) {
            allTables.remove();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike!

This was exactly what I was looking for - much appreciated!